# Effect dependencies and ability adding/removing effects

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have an abstract question about MTG comprehensive rules, regarding 613. *Interaction of Continuous Effects*.

Suppose I have some active continuous effects A, B, C (given in timestamp order) in layer 7. Suppose A depends on C: rule 613 tells me I need to apply the effects in the following order: B, C, A.

Now a new continuous effect D is created in layer 6, which removes all abilities from the object that contains the static ability that is producing effect C. After an event occurs, I reevaluate the game state. I have 4 continuous effects, A, B, C and D. Rule 613 tells me to sort them so: D, B, C, A. But right after I apply effect D to the game state, effect C becomes inactive.

My question is: am I supposed to continue applying the remaining effects in the initial order (B, A), or am I supposed to re-sort them into A, B as the dependency that forced B to come before A no longer exists?

Comment: I get that this is an abstract hypothetical that you already answered, but I'm wondering how dependencies even would show up in Layer 7 (or specifically in some sublayer of layer 7).  It seems like it would have to be a static ability that is worded something like "1/1 creatures get +2/+2" or something like that.  Since this would feel like a weird paradox to most casual players, I don't think they would ever print something like that, but I could be wrong.  Still interesting to consider since the rules do account for something like that.

Answer (score 4):

Never mind, I shouldn't be reading comprehensive rules late at night...

*613.7c After each effect is applied, the order of remaining effects is reevaluated and may change if an effect that has not yet been applied becomes dependent on or independent of one or more other effects that have not yet been applied.*